# Converting Express app from promises to async/await

Tags: javascript, express, es6-promise

I've been using Promises for a long time and I've always disliked how bulky written code looked. So it makes sense that I love async/await (in theory).

However, you can only use await within an async function. If I currently have each route as a function (ex `export function createLike(req, res, next)`), can that route be an `async function`? Is there anything I need to check if I do that? Or do strange things happen if I do that? I could keep the function as a normal function with an `async function` called within it like so (if that's the case):

```
export function createLike(req, res, next) {
    doStuff()  // does this need to be "await doStuff()" if it's the only actionable call in the parent function?

    async function doStuff() {
        // do asynchronous stuff via async/await
        res.status(200).send('success')
    }
}
```

Comment: `does this need to be "await doStuff()"` is doStuff asynchronous? (doesn't look asynchronous) - how can we help with converting if you don't show what the original code is?

Comment: I guess you could use, async for nodeJS. Check for the waterfall function

Comment: @JaromandaX `doStuff()` is asynchronous. I didn't think specific asynchronous code was important, just that it needs to be asynchronous.
@YoannPicquenot why is the waterfall function required? Using async/await allows you to chain the various async functions without the need for waterfall. Or do you mean it's just easier?

Comment: in that case, `await doStuff` - or even `return await doStuff` seems like the correct thing to do ... again, you say you're converting from promises to async/await, but without the code you're converting from, it's hard to tell exactly how you should convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export async function createLike(req, res, next) {
```

Easy-peasy. Declaring a function as async does little more than make it return a Promise.

Unravelling your whole trivial example:

```
export async function createLike(req, res, next) {
  // Don't bother putting inside a 'doStuff' if it's all you have.
  // Get straight to the asyncing
  const { something } = await someAsyncMethod();
  const { foo } = await fetch(`/get/this/${something}`).then((r) => r.json());
  console.log(foo);
  res.status(200).send('success')
}
```

This will wait until it gets `someAsyncMethod()`s response, then fetches something, before sending the response.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. And the fact that the function is returning a promise shouldn't affect any affect on subsequent routes (ex. error handling route), correct?

Comment: That's right - afaik express doesn't use the return values of its functions for anything, so the fact that it's returning a promise should go unnoticed. btw I don't know who this sociopath is going through and downvoting literally everything in this question without explanation...

Comment: Awesome. I'll run that through our test servers for a bit to make sure nothing wonky happens. I'll update you like cli, if all is well, you won't hear from me again. If something goes wrong, I'll let you know lol. And I don't know either, just a bad day I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Use `koa` 2+. Its built for `async/await` stuff.

Comment: I suggest you convert it to koa since Express is outdated in general and especially in this context.

Comment: That's a significantly larger undertaking. I can easily convert endpoints 1 at a time to `async/await` instead of having to move everything over to `koa`. I will definitely keep this in mind for the next project though.